# URGENT =IF(C3>37.6,"high"), IF(C3<36.6,"low"),IF(AND(C3>36.7,C3<37.5,"normal"))) is this formula right

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

[The second half of the formula doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMfry.jpg) If body temperature of patient (t) < 36,6, it is low, from 36,7 to 
37,5 - normal, greater than 37,6 - high. 
This is the information to create the formula
Please reply

Answer (score 1):

> =IF(C3>37.6,“high”), IF(C3<36.6,“low”),IF(AND(C3>36.7,C3<37.5,“normal”))) is this formula right

No, this formula is not right. If formula's take 2 parameters and start and end with brackets.

```
=if( condition, true, false)
```

So your formula should be this:

```
=if(C3>37.6,                                       )
             "high",
                     if(C3 <36.6,                 )
                                  "low",          
                                         "normal"
```

so:

```
=if(C3>37.6, "high", if(C3 <36.6, "low", "normal"))
```

The first if checks if the temperature is higher than 37.6. If not, then we check if it is lower than 36.6. If not either, then we are always left with a temperature between these two values, so we do not need to evaluate anything and just return "normal".

Comment: I just attached a photo of when I tried the formula, the second half doesn't work and as a result all my results are "high"

Comment: @Kate can you upload the excel sheet to http://ge.tt ?

Comment: @Kate LPChip's thing works  https://i.imgur.com/5fdSYl5.png

Comment: @Kate I think I know what you are doing wrong. You maybe have C3 in all of them? Your C3 IS HIGH. But when you are in other rows, you don't want C3 there, you want C4, C5 e.t.c..  Really you should learn how to do something basic when things aren't urgent. Like how to make a column that is the +1 from another column

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/gc8qPef.png  or even https://i.imgur.com/5AUESAh.png